# Rails Rspec default view test cannot assign model stub

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, rspec2

I am trying to understand the Rspec default view specs that is generated when a scaffold is built, and why they don't' work.
I am using;
Rails 4.0.2
Rspec 2.14.7

```
spec/views/line_items/new.html.erb_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe "line_items/new" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:line_item, stub_model(LineItem,
      :product => nil,
      :cart => nil
    ).as_new_record)
  end

  it "renders new line_item form" do
    render

    assert_select "form[action=?][method=?]", line_items_path, "post" do
      assert_select "input#line_item_product[name=?]", "line_item[product]"
      assert_select "input#line_item_cart[name=?]", "line_item[cart]"
    end
  end
end
```

Rspec doesn't seem to recognize line_item. There are no validations on LineItem to prevent creating a new one.
In the index spec the assign does create valid line_items, but I was only able to access them through the @_encapsulated_assigns instance variable.

```
spec/views/line_items/index.html.erb_spec.rb

require 'spec_helper'

describe "line_items/index" do
  before(:each) do
    assign(:line_items, [
      stub_model(LineItem,
        :product => nil,
        :cart => nil
      ),
      stub_model(LineItem,
        :product => nil,
        :cart => nil
      )
    ])
  end

  it "renders a list of line_items" do
    render
    line_item = @_encapsulated_assigns[:line_items].first
    assert_select "tr>td>a[href=?]", line_item_path(line_item)
    assert_select "tr>td>a[href=#{line_item_path(line_item)}]", text: "Show"
  end
end
```

The examples in the Rspec 2.14 documentation don't cover asset_select or assign .as_new_record, nor do they directly access any of the stubs created.
Any help is appreciated:)

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn't recognize"? There are no references to a `line_item` variable/method in your test. What error are you getting?

Comment: I thought that the assign line_item, stub_model was creating a callable object. It seems that the assert_select statements are relying on the fact that there is a line_item[product], and line_item[cart]. When I put a puts line_item in the test it says "undefined local variable or method 'line_item'".

Comment: The arguments to `assert_select` are CSS selectors, not Ruby expressions.